# Black screen gets flashed when loading a new Fragment with an ExoPlayer2 to play a new video

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to play videos that I store locally in my `res`-folder. I need ExoPlayer2's capability of changing the playback speed. In practice I load different kinds of Fragments into a `FrameLayout`. 
When I want to play a video I first create an ExoPlayer2 instance and load the new media file into it. Afterwards, I wait till the player is in playback state `Player.READY` and then load my new Fragment. In the `onCreateView()`-method of the Fragment I attach the `SurfaceView` of the Fragment to the ExoPlayer instance. 
Unfortunately, the Fragment flashes a black screen for maybe 30 to 100 milliseconds before playing my video and I consider that behavior to be undesirable for the user experience and want that once the Fragment is rendered it immediately starts playing the video.

I uploaded a minimized example to [Github](https://github.com/ChristianKleineidam/VideoProblems) to illustrate the problem and also create a [ticket](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4303#issuecomment-393562446) on ExoPlayer2's repository.

To provide a few lines of the code of the example:

The `onCreateView()` method in the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videolayout, container, false);
    mContext = inflater.getContext();
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mPlayer = activity.getPlayer();

    mPlayer.setVideoSurfaceView((SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surface_view1));
    mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    return view;
}
```

The function that loads the new video file:

```
private void playVideo(Context context, String name){
    final int raw_res_id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
            name,
            "raw",
            context.getPackageName());
    MediaSource media_source = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(getDataSourceFactory()).createMediaSource(
            RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(raw_res_id));
    mPlayer.prepare(media_source);
    mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
}
```

The functions that load the new Fragment:

```
private void waitTillReady(){
    if (mPlayer.getPlaybackState() == Player.STATE_READY){
        createNewFragment();
    }
    else{
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                waitTillReady();
            }
        }, 10);
    }
}

private void createNewFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.contentFragment, new VideoFragment());
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Why would you create a new Fragment when player is ready? You might want to do some stuff in background as well. So first you should prepare your views, then you should show a loading animation while the video player is initialized, then just hide the animation when video is ready; just let it play. Also, I would recommend using `mPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener()` and listen to state changes in `onPlayerStateChanged`; I've just tried and it worked.

Comment: Played around a bit with your source code, and as I can see, the default background of the video player is black, thus I think the video just loads a bit then displays.

Comment: @FilipLuch : What exactly do you mean with "prepare your views"? I don't use the listener because in production I also wait for another condition before playing the video. 
Why do I need to show a loading animation between showing video 1 and showing video 2? (Yes, I do need new Fragments)

Comment: I mean to actually inflate all the fragments you need, then do the data loading for it. The animation I mentioned was just so that you can track when video is loading and when it actually plays. I tried inflating the fragment before, then loading the video inside the fragment and I can see the video default black background, and I suppose the flickering is caused by doing two things at a time: inflating the fragment and loading the video. You're doing all at once and heavy UI stuff. That doesn't sound right. Do the UI, then load the data without blocking the UI.

Comment: @Christain Did you find any solution for this one, I am facing the same issue, found the issue on git reported by U, but found no solution https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4303. Please Help

Comment: @RenjithKN : (1) If you consider this an important question, upvote it. It feels a bit rude to me to not find the question important enough to upvote and ask in this way. (2) I haven't solved the bug on that level. If you have the same problem, it would make sense to go to the github issue and voice your problems. If more people voice that this bug is a problem for them that incentives the maintainers to fix it.

Comment: @Christian Thank you for the response. (1) Already upvoted, even before posting my first comment. (2) Yes will follow up there too...